# Non Nomination Nominations

Tags: discussion, election

There are currently two self nominations for the Moderator election that are not nominations. Looking at the rules, I see that

> After 7 days, the top 30 nominees, ordered by reputation, advance to
>   the primary phase. However, if there are 10 candidates or less, we
>   skip directly to the election phase.

We are currently at 9 total nominations including these 2 non-nominations, which means we are more likely to go into the primary phase. Is it appropriate to ask them to remove their nomination in the comments?

Comment: I miss that part. I'll remove mine.

Comment: Thanks for being a moderator @Saariko!

Comment: The first time I saw this I read it as 'Nom Nominations'.

Comment: I'd like to nominate myself for a nom nomination. Mmm . . . donuts.

Comment: Come to the SFSE breakfast meetup at Dreamforce and we will nom nom on some good breakfast!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As a rule, we do not interfere in the election process, but nomination slots are certainly not the appropriate place to comment on how great the site is (even though it is!). I removed Tepsi's nomination. With Saariko also withdrawing his, I think we're all good now.

Policy-wise, it is certainly appropriate to comment on all nominations to ask folks to flesh out their pitches or to remind them that nominations should be ...well... nominations. Serious ones at that. (In the sense that the person nominating should actually want the job. Humorous write-ups are fine. :))

If you see another non-nomination, feel free to comment on my answer here and I'll clear it out.

Good luck to all candidates!